# Inconsistency in axios requests to Express/Node backend with CORS error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, cors

I've been having real issues making secure API calls from a React frontend (AWS Amplify) to a Node/Express backend (AWS EC2) via an EC2 Elastic Load Balancer. I am using Auth0 for authentication and everything works locally but then I have issues when moving online.

I've fixed most of the issues (i.e. register interceptors, etc to attach the bearer token) but have an ongoing issue where I think `axios` is sending a preflight `OPTIONS` request simultaneously with my `GET` request which will then fail. If I move from various pages swiftly then eventually a second slightly delayed `GET` request that will succeed, but not have a separate preceding preflight `OPTIONS`. This is why I am wondering if `axios` is jumping the gun on the initial `GET` or if they are displayed separately only if the `GET` fails.

The error I see in Chrome's console is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.DOMAIN/api/requirementgroups' from origin 'https://www.DOMAIN' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here's an example with some details where I could see differences in the logs

- Preflight - 09:41:29 - no authentication token set in the header and response headers include  `access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE; access-control-allow-headers: authorization`
- Get -  09:41:29 - authentication token in header, all response headers `content-length: 524 content-type: text/html date: Thu, 16 Mar 2023 09:41:29 GMT server: awselb/2.0`
- Get -  09:41:31 - authentication token in header, response headers include `access-control-allow-methods: GET, OPTIONS; access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, Authorization`

Screenshot of the Network tab:

[image]

My server has the following setup (I have tried various setups):

```
app.options('*', cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});
```

There are a lot of similar questions on StackOverflow which I've spent the last week reading but can't get to the bottom of it - partly I think because the error in the console is a bit of a catch all so doesn't given a specific issue to fix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm new to all this so I'm hoping I'm doing something silly that is obvious to those with more experience...

Comment: That 502 response status to the actual request has nothing to do with CORS.

Comment: Ah thanks... helps me narrow it down a bit anyway... so the CORS error message in the console is because the 502 response returns no headers? Given my local node server works fine I assume there's an intermittent issue between the load balancer and the EC2 server, but I think this only started once I implemented authentication so it feels a bit odd. No errors are printing to my EC2 Node console and I'm seeing regular status check requests from the load balancer printed to the console.

Comment: _so the CORS error message in the console is because the 502 response returns no headers?_ Yes, the message is saying that the ACAO header is missing in the response to the _actual_ request. The absence of that header is likely a consequence of whatever is causing that 502 response, but the CORS issue you're observing is not the cause of that 502 response.

Comment: In case people reach here in the future... jub0bs helped me realise it wasn't a CORS problem (despite the CORS error being printed first in the console, not helpful for beginners!). Most requests weren't reaching my API on an EC2 instance and the only thing between them was a load balancer, looking at that I could see it was getting 502 errors from the destination EC2 server (although they weren't appearing on my API logs). Got the logs from the load balancer saving to a S3 bucket and then saw it was sending requests onwards to multiple ports.

Comment: My final conclusion is that most of the time the response from the inactive port would be faster than the port with my active API, and this error would be passed on. Sometimes the positive response from my API would beat the error from the alternative port, and this is where the inconsistency was coming from. I changed the load balancer to only forward to the correct port everything was fine. I changed ports after finding 1the original port was occupied on my new OS, naively I thought the load balancer would send requests to all ports and the inactive port wouldn't be an issue. Thanks jub0bs!